# How can I have the symbols in a shared library override existing symbols?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen

I want to load a shared library with `dlopen` and have the symbols in it available without having to individually grab function pointers to them with `dlsym`.  The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) says that the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag will place lookup of symbols in the library ahead of global scope, but evidently this does not mean it overrides existing symbols because this does not work.  Consider this example:

main.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int is_loaded(){return 0;}

int main(){
    void *h = dlopen("./libimplementation.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
    if(!h){
        printf("Could not load implementation: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    puts(is_loaded() ? "Implementation loaded" : "Implementation not loaded");
    dlclose(h);
}
```

implementation.c:

```
int is_loaded(){return 1;}
```

Makefile:

```
all: main libimplementation.so

main: main.c
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o $@ $^ -ldl

lib%.so: %.c
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o $@ $^ -shared

clean:
    -rm main *.so
```

When I build and run with `make` and `./main`, I expect the `test()` function from `libimplementation.so` to override the `test()` function from `main` but it doesn't.  I know I could also move all of the code in `main()` into another shared library `run` and then have `main()` `dlopen` `libimplementation.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL` and then have `librun.so` refer to the symbols from `libimplementation.so` without having them defined so it loads them:

modified main.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(){
    void *impl_h = dlopen("./libimplementation.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if(!impl_h){
        printf("Could not load implementation: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    void *run_h = dlopen("./librun.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!run_h){
        printf("Could not load run: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(impl_h);
        return 1;
    }
    void (*run)(void);
    *(void**)&run = dlsym(run_h, "run");
    if(!*(void**)&run){
        printf("Could not find entry point in run: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(impl_h);
        dlclose(run_h);
        return 1;
    }
    run();
    dlclose(impl_h);
    dlclose(run_h);
}
```

run.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_loaded(void);

void run(void){
    puts(is_loaded() ? "Implementation loaded" : "Implementation not loaded");
}
```

and the `Makefile` gets `librun.so` added as a prerequisite for `all`.

Is there a way to get the symbols from the shared library available all at once without `dlsym` or putting the actual code in another shared library like with `librun.so`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is fundamentally no way to do what you're asking for. Imagine the main program had something like:

```
static char *myptr = array_in_lib1;
```

Later, at the time you `dlopen`, `myptr` has some other value. Has the program just changed the variable to point to a different object? Or has it been incremented to point to some element later in the array - in which case, would you want it adjusted to account for the redefinition of `array_in_lib1` with a new definition from the newly-opened library? Or is it just a random integer cast to `char *`? Deciding how to treat it is impossible without understanding *programmer intent* **and** *full process history* of how it arrived in the current state.

The above is a particulrly egregious sort of example I've constructed, but the idea of symbols changing definition at runtime is fundamentally inconsistent in all sorts of ways. Even `RTLD_DEEPBIND`, in what it already does, is arguably inconsitent and buggy. Whatever you're trying to do, you should find another way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I had this question because I have a bunch of shared libraries with the same set of exposed functions to test which im currently doing with dlsym and it works fine.  I agree this would be really brittle and a bad idea typically, but mostly because of what could happen if the shared library has unexpected symbols.  I don't agree that it's impossible, at worst you could have the program fork, gdb itself, find all the symbols in the shared library that are in the original program, and overwrite them, but that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @hacatu: That's not the "at worst". There is fundamentally no way to find all references and change them without (doing the equivalent of) restarting the program from the beginning, which is not possible if it interacts with the outside world in any way rather than just processing predetermined input. I tried to explain why in this answer - references can be simply *based on*, rather than directly equal to, symbols, and they can also be false matches by chance. Further, they can be impossible to find, e.g. if you asked an external process to encrypt your pointers for you & only stored result.

Comment: What you *could* do, if these are just functions, is overwrite the start of the original functions with jumps to the new replacement, but unless the program is single-threaded this requires a "stop-the-world" primitive that additionally ensures nothing is stopped inside the functions you're replacing. This is highly nontrivial.

Comment: You're right but I just meant the explicit occurrences of the symbols could be overwritten; obviously pointers to these symbols couldn't be updated unless you scanned through all the program's memory and other computed values like you describe couldn't be changed in general unless you could restart the program like you said.  The thing with patching the first instruction in the patched function is interesting, I think I've heard of libraries doing that but offline.  I'm just going to stick to dlsym and assuming no one replys with a hack to do this I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @R.. See [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) for example of automatic generation of such trampolines. It does not cover OP's case but could be easily adapted for this.